# What is the best way to provide an erratum to the public until the journal publishes it, or if it does not?

Tags: publications, publishers

I published an article in a Springer journal. I consider it to be the basis of all my future research. An editor introduced errors right before publication without asking me and now the article, as it was published Online First, cannot be modified. The EiC offered to publish an erratum with my article two issues from now. He is going to have to find out whether Springer publishes online errata. (Do they?) In the meantime, or if the erratum is never published online, what can be done to make the public aware that that is not a correct version of the article? Would you publish a link to the article with your own erratum in your personal website?

Comment: The best thing to do is wait patiently for the publisher to deal with it.  A journal that does not publish errata when the author and editor agree it is needed would be unusual.

Answer (score 1):

Publish a technical report / preprint without the error.

Comment: You could even note (e.g., in a footnote on the opening page) that the publishers introduced errors in their version.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your suggestion. But a preprint would not be the correct final version of the article either.

Comment: @Philosopherofscience You've said correction isn't possible, so there's surely no way to have a correct final version

Comment: I said correction isn't possible within the journal. I am even thinking of asking permission in the long term future to publish the article as part of a book.

Comment: @Philosopherofscience I don't see how that helps in the short-term. Waiting for the publisher to post an errata will be faster.